# Creating a blogging application

Tags: dns

I just planned to create a blogging application in Java. But i am not understanding one thing. say suppose my site is xyz.com and user T registers on site then he can browse it through T.xyz.com. How can this be possible? I googled few sites and found that people on those sites advise to keep wildcard *, so we can catch any subdomain *.domain.com. This is fine but i am working on localhost, and haven't hosted the site. So which domain should i type? and where to type?
I am using Ubuntu 9.10 and Bind

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost can also have subdomains, but you need to fix your local dns to allow it.

Here's what I found (I'm not a linuxer so I can't test it), http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=576.
You also need to do the apache thing equivalent to your server...

> Under linux, it is: /etc/hosts
>
> Open the file, and append a new line with the following:
>   "127.0.0.1    site1.localhost"
>
> Next step is to edit apache httpd.conf file and declare your subdomain.
>   Locate your httpd.conf file and append the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName site1.localhost
  DocumentRoot "path/to/website"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But i am using Glassfish! where i can find this httpd.conf file? I am unable to find this file on my harddrive?Please help
waiting for your comments